# Join two select statements sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, natural-join

I have two sql statements that I wish to join via natural join but for some reason the following is giving me an error:

```
(select city_name
from city
left join country
on country.country_name=city.country_name
where country.continent='Europe'
and city.iscapitol='yes')

natural join

(select city_name
from city
left join country
on country.country_name=city.country_name
where country.continent='Europe'
and city.iscapitol='no';)
```

I am using the oracle platform and the error it is throwing is:

```
natural join
*
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

What would be the reason this error would be appearing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
(select city_name
from city
left join country
on country.country_name=city.country_name
where country.continent='Europe'
and city.iscapitol='yes')

natural join

(select city_name
from city
left join country
on country.country_name=city.country_name
where country.continent='Europe'
and city.iscapitol='no'))
```

I've removed `;` and added outer query. I would also recommend to replace `natural join` by explicit condition for `join`

```
with eurcities as (select city_name, iscapitol, country_name from city
      left join country on country.country_name=city.country_name
      where country.continent='Europe')
select c1.city_name, c2.city_name, c1.country_name 
  from eurcities c1 inner join eurcities c2 on (c1.country_name = c2.country_name) 
  where c1.iscapitol = 'yes' and c2.iscapitol = 'no';
```

Without `with` it will look like:

```
select c1.city_name, c2.city_name, c1.country_name 
  from (select city_name, iscapitol, country_name from city
            left join country on country.country_name=city.country_name
            where country.continent='Europe') c1 
    inner join (select city_name, iscapitol, country_name from city
            left join country on country.country_name=city.country_name
            where country.continent='Europe') c2 
    on (c1.country_name = c2.country_name) 
  where c1.iscapitol = 'yes' and c2.iscapitol = 'no';
```

Comment: @Sal please edit your question and add there structure of your tables and some example data. It will be much easier to advise you with query

Comment: @Sal I've edited answer and added suggested query. Please try it

Comment: `with` clause define data I'm using later in query. You can think about it like about view defined just for one query This prepares data that contains only European cities. `c1` and `c2` are just aliases for table defined in `with` clause. @Sal

Comment: @Sal I've added you also version without `with` but also using aliases

Answer (score 0):

First, unlearn `natural join`.  It is an error waiting to happen.  Not showing the `join` keys in the code is dangerous.  Ignoring declared foreign key relationships is unwise.  Relying on naming conventions is awkward.

You can write this using `using`.  So, fixing the syntax, this looks like:

```
select *
from (select city_name
      from city left join
           country
           on country.country_name = city.country_name
     where country.continent='Europe' and city.iscapitol = 'yes'
    ) cc join
    (select city_name
     from city left join
          country
          on country.country_name = city.country_name
     where country.continent = 'Europe' and city.iscapitol='no'
    ) cnc
    using (city_name);
```

Note that the `left join`s in the subquery are unnecessary.

That said, I think aggregation is a much simpler approach to the query:

```
      select city_name
      from city join
           country
           on country.country_name = city.country_name
      where country.continent = 'Europe'
      having sum(case when city.iscapitol = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when city.iscapitol = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Or, if `iscapitol` [sic] only takes on two values, you can use this for the `having` clause:

```
      having min(city.iscapitol) <> max(city.iscapitol)
```